# iPhone - I can't edit the constraints of my navigation bar button

Tags: iphone, swift, uibutton, autolayout

Is there a way I can do this with code? I have a navigation bar button in the middle and I can't seem to add any constraints. The problem is that while it IS in the middle for iPhone 6's, it's askew for other iPhones. I would have to change the inset and then it messes up regardless.

Comment: how did you end up putting a navigation bar button item in the middle? the only two place you can use are left and right no? please provide more info...Maybe in your case it will be better to place a custom uiview? are using a navigation bar?

Comment: @IamMashed Yeah I'm not sure either, but it worked. Just dragged it over there. Can you elaborate on the custom UIView?

Comment: remove the navigation Item and instead just place the UIView with the width of screen.width and customize height you want. Put your button on this UIView. Constraint setup will be easy after that

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Instead of abandoning the first question, _edit_ it.

Comment: @matt this isn't a duplicate but I suppose I understand what you mean. Regardless I haven't gotten an answer.